# How to lookup in a static hashmap?

Tags: javascript

How can I retrieve the keys of a static initialized map in JavaScript?

```
var inputMap = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
};

inputMap.get(2);
```

Result:
`TypeError: inputMap.get() is not a function`.

(I feel kind of stupid asking that question, but coming from Java I cannot see any error in this example)

Comment: simply use `inputMap[2]`

Comment: Retrieve the keys, or retrieve the property referred to by that key? Note also this is not a hash map, it's an object with properties whose names happen to be numbers. (Whether or not this is a good idea depends on the specific problem being solved.) Maybe a JS tutorial would be a good place to start.

Comment: Your attempt looks more like an `array lists`. In JS there are none. You can access property of objects just with their keys, so you could also do: `let foo = { 'hello': 10}; console.log(foo['hello'])`. Ofc there are normal arrays :D

Comment: (And it's not "static" in any meaningful way.)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with brackets.

```js
var inputMap = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
};

console.log(inputMap[2]);
```

Or take [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get), which returns the same result.

```js
var inputMap = {
    0: 'a',
    1: 'b',
    2: 'c'
};

console.log(Reflect.get(inputMap, 2));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using:

1. Dot notation

```
const inputMap = {
   0: 'a',
   1: 'b',
   2: 'c',
   three: 'd'

};

inputMap.three // the result will be 'd' in this case
inputMap.2 // the dot notation will not work in this case
```

2. Bracket notation

```
const inputMap = {
 0: 'a',
 1: 'b',
 2: 'c'
};

inputMap['2']
```

Comment: Yes this sadly works.. `inputMap[2]` and `inputMap['2']` both return c

Comment: Nah both work. I tested it. Maybe if you `"use strict;"` one doesn't work.

Comment: @Elias in what environment is the first one not a syntax error?

Comment: @Elias Under what circumstances? A digit is an illegal token in this context; dot access to properties require a legal identifier.

Comment: Uhm I just executed this and it worked in both cases: `"use strict";

const foo = {
 1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c'
};

console.log(foo[1], foo['1']);`. I'm on chrome if it helps

Comment: @Elias Uhm neither of which is `inputMap.2` so you might want to clarify your comment, because everyone thinks you mean the two examples shown in the question you commented on. That's why we tag comments to users--to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh @DaveNewton There is our problem. The owner(the one that answered) removed `inputMap[2]` So I thought we were talking about this... sorry

Comment: @NicolaeMaties The first example with dot notation is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, for this example it doesn't work. For some other example that has other key than a number it will work. I will update the answer.